# When using window load function it says $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So I am using a wordpress theme called : thalassa.

I went to [this site](http://yokohama.hr/portfoliomas.html) and copied the portfolio.js code. (note: my portfolio.js is exactly the same except the first line)

portfolio.js :

```
$(window).load(function() {
/* ================ VERFIFY IF USER IS ON TOUCH DEVICE ================ */

if(is_touch_device()){
    $(".portfolio-image").on('click', function(e){                  
        $(this).find('.portfolio-hover').show();
    });
}

// function to check is user is on touch device
function is_touch_device() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in window // works on most browsers 
    || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; // works on ie10
}

/* ================ PORTFOLIO ISOTOPE FILTER ================ */

(function() {
    //ISOTOPE
    // cache container
    var $portfolioitems = $('#portfolioitems');
    // initialize isotope
    $portfolioitems.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 1,
            isResizable: true
        }
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').click(function() {
        $('#filters li').removeClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').end().attr('data-filter');
        $portfolioitems.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });
})();
});
```

Then I paste it into my own site and it says : $ is not a function.
Why does it work on that site and not on my site? What am I doing wrong? Before I added

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

I had

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

It works but sometimes it bugs out. And on the site I linked it doesn't.

Comment: Have you included jQuery.js in the page?

Comment: did you included jquery ..??

Comment: Pasted it where? Wordpress is cranky and loads jquery after everything so it's not loaded when you try run your code

Comment: Wordpress use jQuery noConflict(), so $ reference is removed

Comment: You could just use jQuery(window) and pass $ through like you were doing earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO it like this way,

```
( function($) {

    //Code block here
    $(window).load( function() {
        // do Stuff
    });

    $(document).ready( function() {
        //Wiggle Wiggle
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function () {
 //something
```

});

This function is depreciated, you can use :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery word insted of $ in wordpress.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

-------

});
```